# Proof that $F(a) = \int_0^{+\infty} e^{-(x-a)^2}dx$ is a continuous function

Tags: integration

Let $F(a) = \displaystyle\int_0^{+\infty} e^{-(x-a)^2}dx$ is a parametrics integral. Proof that F is continuous.
Here 's my effort: 
$$t = x - a $$
We have
$$F(a) = \displaystyle \int_{-a}^{+\infty} e^{-t^2}dt = \displaystyle \int_{-a}^0 e^{-t^2}dt + \displaystyle \int_0^{+\infty} e^{-t^2}dt = \displaystyle \int_{0}^a e^{-t^2}dt + \displaystyle \int_0^{+\infty} e^{-t^2}dt $$
$ f(a) = \displaystyle \int_{0}^a e^{-t^2}dt$ is continuous because $e^{-t^2}$ is bounded and continuous on $(0,+\infty) \times \mathbb{R}$ 
$$ \displaystyle \int_0^{+\infty} e^{-t^2}dt  = \dfrac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2} < \infty $$ then $F(a)$ is continuous.

Is my proof right or wrong? My lectures said that I need to proof the uniform convergence of the improper integral but I can't understand how to do that. Can anybody tell me more clearly about this exercise. Thanks

Comment: $$ \displaystyle \int_0^{+\infty} e^{t^2}dt  = \dfrac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}$$  this is not true. this is true:$$ \displaystyle \int_0^{+\infty} e^{-t^2}dt  = \dfrac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}$$

Comment: I have a mistake on the first post. The excercise is $e^{-(x-a)^2}$ instead of $e^{(x-a)^2}$

Comment: Hint: $|F(a) - F(c)| = \left|\int_a^c e^{-t^2} \, dt  \right| $

Answer (score 3):

Yes, what you have shown is correct. Indeed, you have shown that 
$$
F(a)=\int_{-a}^0e^{-t^2}\mathrm dt+\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}
$$
is differentiable, by the fundamental theorem of calculus and since $e^{-t^2}$ is continuous. The derivative is 
$$
F'(a)=e^{-a^2}
$$
So it is continuous.